# The Words 'Transport Equation'

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

Hi I come from a mathematical stochastic background. In PDE / ODE / analysis I sometimes hear the terminology 'transport equation' or 'transport part of the equation'.

Can anyone explain $\textbf{In General}$ what someone is referring to when they talk about $\textit{'A transport equation or the transport part of the equation'}$. If anyone can explain this from a mathematical or physical perspective that would be amazing.

I just want enough so that I can have a general idea of what someone is talking about when they mention this 'transport'.

Note I am not talking about Optimal Transport theory which Im confident is not related.

Comment: Actually optimal transport theory and transport/continuity equations are highly related.

Answer (score 1):

In its most simple form, this is the equation
$$
0=u_t+cu_x
$$
which has solutions of the form $u(x,t)=v(x-ct)$, which also identifies $c$ as the velocity of the transport. This means that the form of the solution at time zero is transported unchanged to the right on the $x$ axis with velocity $c$.

---

Note that you can in reverse also compute traveling solutions in some equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)
$$
by inserting just that form $u(x,t)=v(x-ct)$ to get a second order ODE
$$
0=v''+cv'+f(v)
$$
which resembles the kinetic equation of a particle in a force field and under frictional loss of energy. Usually you get boundary conditions for $v(x)$ like ending in roots of $f$ at $x=\pm\infty$